# How to prevent summernote from popping open all modals?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, summernote

On rendering summer note all modals appear open with the help modal at the top most of the stack. I am unable to close any of them. Not using bower or anything else. A simple application hosted with bottle python. No JS errors. From element inspector if I check the rendering is correct and functional too.

The stacked up modals that appear on rendering:

[image]

Just this from JS console : NO OEMBED

Comment: can you show live example?

Comment: mm.. not really.. are you unable to view the image? By default on page launch its like all the modals of summernote are open: the link, the help, etc. etc.

Comment: yes i can see.i also use summernote but there is no problem like this.so without seeing your code/demo i don't think it's possible to detect the problem.if you can create a jsfiddle simple example reproducing the problem.then it's big help people to detect the problem

Comment: ok.. i figured it. apparently the bootstrap version of my template is old (2.3.2). I just added a display:none on the modal class and then the behavior is fine. Appreciate your time and prompt reply @FastSnail.

Comment: you can answer your own question.good luck

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the bootstrap version of my template is old (2.3.2). I just added a "display:none" on the modal class of the css and then the behavior is fine.

The pop ups behave open and correctly after this.